# How to convert separated values into one-hot encoded columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I have dataframe which looks like this which has food choices and user IDs as columns:

```
        Food choices
1   0   Pizza | Hamburger
2   1   Sushi | Pizza | Pasta | Steak | Noodles
3   2   
4   3   French Fries | Hot dogs | Prawns
5   4   Bacon | Meatballs
6   5   Mozeralla Sticks
```

I want to split them up as something like this:

```
User_ID, Pizza, Hamburger, Sushi, Pasta, ...
1, True, True, False, False, ...
2, True, False, True, True, ...
```

I have split them up as:

```
df['Food Choices'].fillna('None').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split('|'))).fillna('None').replace('None',np.nan)
```

Now I do have them in separate columns but I a struggling with how to Mark presence/absence of a value.
I was thinking along the lines of separating out each value and comparing each value with dataframe as:

```
lst = list(pd.unique(df['Food choices'].fillna('None').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split('|'))).fillna('None').values.ravel('K')))
temp = df['Food choices'].fillna('None').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split('|'))).fillna('None')
dfs = pd.DataFrame(columns = lst,
            index = temp.index)
for val in lst:
    for idx in temp.index:
        dfs.loc[idx, val] = (temp.loc[idx]  == val).any()
```

Way toooo ugly and way toooooo slow! So I was thinking maybe there is some function I maybe missing out which can help me in this regards. `pd.get_dummies()` does not help. Any suggestion how to better this situation will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `str.get_dummies`

```
s = df['Food choices'].str.replace(' \| ','|').str.strip().str.lower().str.get_dummies('|')
df = df.join(s)
```

Cause of the random order in which they occur sometimes space would be next to separator and sometimes won't will cause doubling of column names one with space and one without. This will help in any situation.

Comment: So novel and one shot for one-hot encoding!

Comment: But a little issue tho: `str.get_dummies(' | ')` tend to add a column for `|` as well. `str.get_dummies('|')` resolves  this issue but creates two columns for eachentries even when used as: `.str.strip().str.lower().str.get_dummies(' | ')`

Comment: looks like if you just leave out the arg it works as desired

Comment: One problem is redundant columns `>>> s.columns
Index([' Hamburger', ' Hot dogs ', ' Meatballs', ' Noodles', ' Pasta ', ' Pizza ', ' Prawns', ' Steak ', 'Bacon ', 'French Fries ', 'Mozeralla Sticks', 'Pizza ', 'Sushi '], dtype='object')`. Pizza shows up twice. Row 1 has `Pizza | Hamburger' while row 2 has 'Sushi | Pizza | Pasta | ....'

Comment: Yupp @JoeFerndz I proposed an edit for that. It might be approved soon

Comment: I think you can solve that by doing this. `s = df['Food choices'].str.get_dummies(' | ').drop(['|'],axis=1)`. The edit you proposed is not really necessary.

Comment: With the earlier response from @BEN_YO + using drop option, you will get the desired result `Index(['Bacon', 'French', 'Fries', 'Hamburger', 'Hot', 'Meatballs', 'Mozeralla', 'Noodles', 'Pasta', 'Pizza', 'Prawns', 'Steak', 'Sticks', 'Sushi', 'dogs'], dtype='object')`

Comment: and since your original request was to get True or False value instead of 1 and 0, you can do `s = df['Food choices'].str.get_dummies(' | ').drop(['|'],axis=1).astype(bool)` This will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: @JoeFerndz this is not the desired result as it splits based on space as well which I don't want as it will ruin my `Mozzarella Sticks`, `Hot dogs` & `French Fries` and other things I really like :)

Comment: Yes. I agree. I was looking at all the results. get_dummies is not solving for your problem. Even with the string replace. At least for me.

Comment: fixed it. Try this `s = df['Food choices'].str.replace(' \| ', ',').str.strip().str.get_dummies(',').astype(bool)` or you can give `str.replace(' | ','|',regex=False)`

Comment: This is now perfection!